# How to extract the bootloader from an iso?

Tags: dd, boot-loader, iso

I found a project on *GitHub* that emulates a *Windows XP* operating system, and I have a problem with an *iso*.

- https://github.com/lrusso/VirtualXP/tree/main

I want to extract it, change things and recreate the iso.

The problem is that it doesn't extract the *bootloader*, so when I boot the new one with *Qemu*, it doesn't start the system.

So, it occurred to me that the bootloader could be extracted using `dd`, but it seems impossible.

```js
isoinfo -d -i /mnt/sda2/windows/vxp/VirtualXP.iso
Setting input-charset to 'UTF-8' from locale.
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: 
Volume id: VirtualXP
Volume set id: 20210310_1500                                                                                                                  
Publisher id: MagicISO v5.2 COPYRIGHT (C) 2001-2006 MagicISO, Inc.
Data preparer id: MagicISO v5.2 COPYRIGHT (C) 2001-2006 MagicISO, Inc.
Application id: 
Copyright File id:                                     
Abstract File id:                                     
Bibliographic File id:                                     
Volume set size is: 0
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 22250
El Torito VD version 1 found, boot catalog is in sector 22248

Joliet with UCS level 3 found.
No SUSP/Rock Ridge present
Eltorito validation header:
    Hid 1
    Arch 0 (x86)
    ID 'MagicISO Boot Record'
    Cksum 16 E7 OK
    Key 55 AA
    Eltorito defaultboot header:
        Bootid 88 (bootable)
        Boot media 0 (No Emulation Boot)
        Load segment 0
        Sys type 6
        Nsect 4
        Bootoff 56E9 22249
```

And when I create it again it looks like this, without it working in the emulator:

```js
isoinfo -d -i /mnt/sda2/windows/vxp/vxp0.iso
Setting input-charset to 'UTF-8' from locale.
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: LINUX
Volume id: VXP0
Volume set id: 
Publisher id: 
Data preparer id: 
Application id: MKISOFS ISO9660/HFS/UDF FILESYSTEM BUILDER & CDRECORD CD/DVD/BluRay CREATOR (C) 1993 E.YOUNGDALE (C) 1997 J.PEARSON/J.SCHILLING
Copyright File id: 
Abstract File id: 
Bibliographic File id: 
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 22935
El Torito VD version 1 found, boot catalog is in sector 79
CD-ROM uses ISO 9660:1999 relaxed format

Joliet with UCS level 3 found.
SUSP signatures version 1 found
Rock Ridge signatures version 1 found
Rock Ridge id 'RRIP_1991A'
Eltorito validation header:
    Hid 1
    Arch 0 (x86)
    ID ''
    Cksum AA 55 OK
    Key 55 AA
    Eltorito defaultboot header:
        Bootid 88 (bootable)
        Boot media 0 (No Emulation Boot)
        Load segment 0
        Sys type 0
        Nsect 4
        Bootoff 50 80
```

I tried with sector number `22249`, and it didn't work:

```bash
dd if="$1" of=bootloader.bin bs=1024 skip=$sector count=1024
```

I changed the name of the bootloader to `grldr` (I imagine that by doing this I am just changing the name), currently the command to generate the iso, I am using the following:

```js
mkisofs -V VXP0 -J -joliet-long -iso-level 4 -D -R -o vxp0.iso -b grldr -c boot/boot.catalog -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table vxp0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the bootloader from an ISO file through [`geteltorito`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man1/geteltorito.1.html) included in `genisoimage`:

```
geteltorito -o bootloader VirtualXP.iso
```

In the manpage description:

```
   geteltorito  is a Perl script which extracts the initial/default El Torito boot image from
   a CD if one exists. It will not extract any of other boot images that are allowed  by  the
   El Torito standard.
```

Comment: I like this script.  Does exactly what my FAQ link does in a script...

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution, however when I recreate the iso it doesn't work. Did you try it in Qemu? I changed bootloader to grldr, I really don't know how to do it. `mkisofs -V VXP0 -J -joliet-long -iso-level 4 -D -R -o vxp0.iso -b grldr -c boot/boot.catalog -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table vxp0`. If it works for you, you could create a repository on GitHub with the new iso.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment in case it earns me the bonus, but I googled "Extract El Torito" and ended up at the:

[Rufus Github Repository - Issue 63](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/63).

In case you don't know what RUFUS is see: [Rufus - Create Bootable USB Drives the Easy Way](https://rufus.ie/en/).  Apparently, issue 63 was a feature request now closed that involves the issue you're trying to resolve.  About halfway down the request is this:

[RUFUS FAQ Section - I'm trying to work with an ISO, but Rufus says it's unsupported](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Im_trying_to_work_with_an_ISO_but_Rufus_says_its_unsupported).

I believe if you perform the steps outlined there, you'll end up with your desired results.

### Summary of Steps

1. Create a USB based on FreeDOS in Rufus.
2. Mount the ISO file you created and look for the Virtual Disk Image that contains the DOS Boot Files
3. Extract those files Back to the root.
4. Modify any `.bat` files if needed.
5. After modification, `dd the entire mounted image back to a USB`

### The El Torito Boot Standard

See the Phoenix's BIOS Manufacturers [published standard on El Torito](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/readings/boot-cdrom.pdf), specifically page 14 for what is actually happening.  Quoting [ISOBuster](https://www.isobuster.com/help/bootable_cd_dvd):

> It is not simply possible to copy a bootable floppy image onto CD or DVD and then hope the medium is now bootable.  The File System really needs to know and needs to provide special structures and volume descriptors (in accordance with the El Torito standard).

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm on Linux, if it works for you you could create a repository on GitHub with the bootloader and the new iso.

Comment: @GAD3R and I aren't going to do  the work for you.  We've given you two correct answer as the script he mentioned does exactly what the FAQ I linked to does.  You can accomplish the steps in the FAQ using Linux.  [7-Zip](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=mips&searchon=names&keywords=7zip) is in the package repository, and any iso can be mounted via the loopback device.

Comment: I would like you to try it and tell if it works, without necessarily uploading the repository.

Answer (score 1):

```
dd if="$1" of=bootloader.bin bs=1024 skip=$sector count=1024
```

You used the wrong block size. The CD-ROM operates on 2048-byte blocks, but the boot code size in the El Torito header is specified in 512-byte blocks for some reason. 4 x 512 bytes = 2048, or exactly 1 CD-ROM block. And the `isoinfo` results indicate the boot block seems to be the very last block in the image.

So:

```
dd if=VirtualXP.iso of=bootloader.bin bs=2048 skip=22249 count=1
```

or maybe just

```
tail -c 2048 VirtualXP.iso > bootloader.bin
```

Hopefully there are no binary offsets within the bootloader that would need to be changed to match your new ISO structure.

Comment: I already tried it in Qemu and it didn't work, I updated the question with the command with which I recreate the iso. If you get it working, you can create a GitHub repository with the bootloader and the new iso.

Comment: Did you use `bs=2048` with that `dd` command? Your original question still says `bs=1024`. If the wrong block size was used, you'd get the wrong part of the image. And the `count=1024` in the command in your question would give you a total of 1024*1024 bytes, while the boot block is just a single 2048-byte block.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it didn't work. Apparently what is being extracted is boot.catalog instead of the bootloader.

Comment: According to the `isoinfo` output, the boot catalog is the block just before the boot block, so you were very close. You should try `bs=2048 skip=22250 count=1` then.

Comment: I already tried, but doing that copies 0 bytes. `0 bytes copied, 0,000363325 s, 0,0 kB/s`